# how to get the value of a checkbox with php and xml

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xml, forms

I'm just learning PHP, XML, AJAX, etc., and I have a form that works fine in general.  But I'm having trouble passing the value/state of a checkbox to my PHP script.

Note that my server doesn't appear to work with POST methods (I'm looking into that separately).  So I'm using GET.  Hopefully that isn't related, but just wanted to note that in case it is relevant.

Here is my simplified HTML file:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showUser(u) {
    alert(u.value);
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","checkbox_test.php?u=" + u.value,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        return false;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form method="get" onsubmit="return showUser(this.checkboxID)">
    <input id="checkboxID" name="checkboxName" value="checkboxValue" type="checkbox">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<div id="txtHint"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my simplified PHP file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php
    $check = $_GET['u'];
    if(isset($check)){
            echo 'True';
        }else{
            echo 'False';
        }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why are you using ajax here and not just submitting the form?

Comment: "my server doesn't work with post methods". That sounds very unlikely unless you have a very unusual setup. Looking in the `$_POST` variables on the server side would get anything submitted via POST. Anyway, when you say "having trouble", what exactly do you mean? Is the variable definitely sent in your ajax request (you can check your browser's network tab to view the request details)? Does the call complete successfully? What gets sent back? It doesn't make much sense to have all the `<html>` etc tags round your PHP file if all you actually want back is "true" or "false".

Comment: First of all, what ADyson said. Secondly, don't use `u.value`, instead you need to get the `boolean` value to see if it is checked or not, so parse a `boolean` returned by `u.checked`. You can `console.log(u.checked)` and then check your console (`F12` or `Cmd+Alt+I`) to see the results before sending.

Comment: Thank you for all the replies! @nogad I'm using Ajax, and PHP because this is a greatly simplified portion of a much larger project in which I'm learning to update only a portion of the page, using Ajax, and I'm learning to write PHP scripts.  So it does look a bit silly out of context, but I *think* it makes sense for the larger project.  In the end, getting u.checked did the trick.  (I wasn't aware of the various properties available to query on htmlInputElements, but I found the documentation, and it makes a bit more sense now..)

Comment: @ADyson regarding the trouble I was having with POST methods, I was getting errors saying "405 Method Not Allowed" errors when using method="post" in my form submission line.  `<form method="post" onsubmit="return showUser(this.checkboxID)">`  I can't say that I understand why that is/was.  I assumed it meant my server was not setup to allow POST requests, but I don't see any options to that effect on my server options.

Comment: yes it does mean that (for that specific URL at least) your server is not configured to allow POST requests. That's very unusual though. What webserver are you using? Apache? You should be able to check in the online documentation how to configure that kind of thing

Comment: I'm currently using Abyss Web Server, running off my local web server.  Eventually, I plan to upload the final project to a hosted web server.  Maybe I'll try that sooner rather than later to see if it works there.  Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use u.checked as it's the attribute used by the input to determine the state of the checkbox, u.value will return checkboxValue

```
<input id="checkboxID" name="checkboxName" value="checkboxValue" type="checkbox">
```

Comment: u.checked did the trick!  Thank you.  Found the documentation on htmlinputElement, which clarified the various properties available!